# eCommerce solution for leasing devices for a monthly fee

Tags: ecommerce, magento, payment-gateway, shopping-cart

What eCommerce solutions there exist which allow leasing type of sales? I am working with a medical tech company whose devices are often leased due to high price point. Now the company would be looking for an opportunity for web based eCommerce solution where one could both

- Buy a device
- Lease a device for X month, monthly charged from a credit card

I am pretty aware of normal click-and-buy e-Commerce platforms (Magento, etc.), but I don't know what kind of options there exist for managing the device leases.

Both self-hosted solutions and SaaS e-Commerce solutions can be considered.